# Using R and plm to estimate fixed-effects models that include interactions with time

Tags: r

I am using `plm()` to estimate fixed-effects models of the form

```
y ~ x + time + time:fixed_trait
```

where `fixed_trait` is a variable that varies across individuals but is constant within individuals.

The point of interacting `time` with `fixed_trait` is to permit the effect of `fixed_trait` to vary across time.  (I am working here from Paul Allison's recent booklet on fixed effects.  Citation appended.)

`plm()` has no trouble estimating coefficients and standard errors for such models.  But `summary.plm()` can't calculate R^2 for these models.  This is the problem that I would like to fix.

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(plm)
tmp <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:3, 2), year=rep(0:1, each=3), 
                  y=rnorm(6), const=rep(1:3, 2))
fe1 <- plm(y ~ year,              index=c('ID', 'year'), data=tmp)
fe2 <- plm(y ~ year + year:const, index=c('ID', 'year'), data=tmp)
summary(fe1)  # works fine
summary(fe2)  # Error in crossprod(t(X), beta) : non-conformable arguments
```

Delving into `plm:::summary.plm` makes the problem clearer.  To calculate R^2, `plm` tries to do this:

```
beta <- coef(fe2)
X <- model.matrix(fe2)
crossprod(t(X), beta)
```

This doesn't work because `beta` only includes estimates for `year1` and `year0:const`, while `X` also includes a column for `year1:const`.  In other words, `X` includes columns for both `year0:const` and `year1:const`, and it's impossible to estimate both of those coefficients.

A workaround is to create the interaction term "by hand" before entering it into the formula:

```
tmp$yearXconst <- tmp$year*tmp$const
fe3 <- plm(y ~ year + yearXconst, index=c('ID', 'year'), data=tmp)
summary(fe3)  # works fine
```

But this is cumbersome.  Short of this, is there anything that I can do to make `summary.plm` work with such models?

===

Allison, Paul D. 2009. Fixed Effects Regression Models. Los Angeles, CA: Sage.  See especially pages 19-21.

Comment: Beginning with `plm` version 1.6-4, this is not a problem anymore as alised coefficients are simply dropped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using

```
fe3 <- plm(y ~ year * const, index = c('ID', 'year'), data = tmp)
```

instead. It even works if you are redundantly including time fixed effects in the `*` interaction (because time is being fixed effect-ed out):

```
fe4 <- plm(y ~ year * const, index = c('ID', 'year'), data = tmp, effect = "twoway")
```

Comment: Given that `*` has to be used instead of `:`, is there a way to suppress the output of non-interaction coefficients?