# R | Large-Sample Fixed-Effects Interaction using plm

Tags: interaction, fixed-effects-model, large-data, plm

How can I model Interactions with fixed effects for a large sample using plm?

I have a panel data set with > 100,000 observations and I am trying to model a dummy-interaction with one of two fixed effect (n ~ 1450).

Following [this suggestions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24131/using-r-and-plm-to-estimate-fixed-effects-models-that-include-interactions-with) I include the interaction explicitly in the model, but also include it in the index since I need to cluster standard errors by the fixed effect. Hence, my model is of the form:

```
table <- plm(y ~ x + x*dummy + ID*dummy, 
             data=panel, index=c("ID","MONTH"), model="within", effect = "twoways")
```

Now the issue is that I am trying to evaluate the model output with robust standard errors clustered by ID using

```
coeftest(table, vcov = vcovHC(table, type = "HC1", cluster="group")).
```

However, due to the large sample this gives my an error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.8 Gb
```

Do you know an alternative way to perform this analysis? Splitting up the sample would not work (I guess). I am open to packages other than plm or getting the output with robust standard errors not using coeftest.

Comment: Not a statistical question. Anyway, look at package `lfe` and try its assocaited functionality for robust standard errors.